# SignalR not calling client methods

Tags: c#, signalr

So I've read all of the other SO questions with regard to this but it looks like everything should be set up properly. I'm running a self-hosted SignalR console application that has a single empty Hub declaration (this is for one-way communication from the server to connected clients).

**EDIT:** Link to project which reproduces the issue - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66477739/SignalRTest.zip

The demo solution has 3 projects:

- SignalRTest.BusinessLogic - Simple console app that just publishes a message every 10 seconds. These messages are never received by the client. This simulates my business logic layer pushing notifications to connected clients.
- SignalRTest.SelfHost - The self-hosted SignalR application + hub. I added a "Send" method to the hub, only to show that everything works when a client calls `server.send('message');` but it doesn't work when the server initiates the message. **Typing in this console window and hitting enter will send that text to the web app. THIS WORKS!**
- SignalRTest.UI - Just a blank MVC app with a single page that loads the necessary scripts. A successfully received message would just log console output, there will never be any UI changes on this sample.

**PublishStatusHub.cs**

```
public class PublishStatusHub : Hub
{
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

    var publish = $.connection.publishStatusHub;

    publish.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() { });
});
```

**Calling code from a separate assembly**

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PublishStatusHub>();
context.Clients.All.addMessage("Starting publish...");
```

Although I can see that the above code is executed (via breakpoints), the client method is never called.

I did turn on SignalR logging and no exceptions are being thrown. Also, it's never logging the incoming messages.

Interestingly enough, I can get messages sent to the client through my Main() method in Program.cs within the self-hosted console app:

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    using (WebApp.Start(url))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

        while (true)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();

            IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PublishStatusHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I type in the console window and hit enter, the message is sent successfully to the client and it's logged in the console output window.

HOWEVER, if I move this code to another file within the same console application and then call it from another assembly (which is the end goal), it fails silently again:

**MessagePublisher.cs**

```
public class MessagePublisher
{
    public void Publish(string message)
    {
        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PublishStatusHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**Calling code from a separate assembly**

```
var messagePublisher = new MessagePublisher();
messagePublisher.Publish("Test message");
```

I'm stuck on why I can't publish messages to connected clients from external assemblies.

Comment: So you setup your signlarR server in console application, then try to publish message from another assembly (while still running the same console application) and it fails?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Maybe you have minimal VS project which reproduces that?

Comment: @Evk - Added a sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project you posted, you are trying to publish a message from completely different console application (`SignalRTest.BusinessLogic`). This application does not host SignalR service, and so has no idea about connected clients. All clients are connected to the service hosted by another application (`SinglaRTest.SelfHost`) in another process. So there is no way how this could work. If you will start your service in `BusinessLogic` application, then this will work as usual.

Comment: The BusinessLogic project calls MessagePublisher.Publish(), which exists in the SelfHost project (and in turn tries to push messages to connected clients -- from within SelfHost). There is no code in the BusinessLogic class which has anything to do with SignalR. Am I understanding your concerns correctly?

Comment: Your BusinessModel is console application, which you run. Yes it references SelfHost, but it does not run SignalR, so why it should be able to publish anything? Dont run BusinessLogic as console application, reference it from host instead.

Comment: To clarify more, only process that hosts signalr can publish messages to clients, you cannot do that from  another processes

Comment: @Scott did you realize the issue after all? If not - I can try to explain in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've created a Constructor, you could remove it...